# Star Rating System in RTL

Tags: html, css

I have a star rating system that build with HTML and CSS only, in left to right it's Work fine, but in Right to left it's still in Left to right,
I want the first star from right filled first and the last one (5) filled recent
How can I make the star direction from right to left filled.

```css
.rate {
  display: flex;
  height: 46px;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.rate:not(:checked)>input {
  position: absolute;
  top: -9999px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.rate:not(:checked)>label {
  float: right;
  width: 1em;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #ccc;
}

.rate:not(:checked)>label:before {
  content: '★ ';
}

.rate>input:checked~label {
  color: #ffc700;
}

.rate:not(:checked)>label:hover,
.rate:not(:checked)>label:hover~label {
  color: #deb217;
}
```

```html
<div class="rate" onclick="validate()">
  <input type="radio" id="star5" class="star" name="rate" value="5" />
  <label for="star5">5 stars</label>
  <input type="radio" id="star4" class="star" name="rate" value="4" />
  <label for="star4">4 stars</label>
  <input type="radio" id="star3" class="star" name="rate" value="3" />
  <label for="star3">3 stars</label>
  <input type="radio" id="star2" class="star" name="rate" value="2" />
  <label for="star2">2 stars</label>
  <input type="radio" id="star1" class="star" name="rate" value="1" />
  <label for="star1">1 star</label>
```

Comment: It seems like that the code you provided is already working as you want: from right to left (?)

Comment: yes, I don't know it's working here but in my website it's not working

Comment: Did you try with "direction" syntax. Probably you can solve it to give it to one of parent classes.

Comment: yes, thank you very much, solved with direction. @GeorgeDiril

Comment: You're welcome. So, I just type it as an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not too sure if your code worked , somehow it seemed to me to work the opposite way hilighting the whole row of stars at first.

You can imbricate flex box, it will inherit the direction flow and if you also wrap the stars in a container , you can reverse it's own flow too to reverse the visual stars notation .

example :

```css
.rate {
  display: flex;
  height: 46px;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
.rate span {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-flow: row-reverse;

  margin:auto 1em;
}
.rtl {
  direction: rtl;
}
.rate:not(:checked) > span input {
  position: absolute;
  right: 100vw;
}

.rate:not(:checked) > span label {
  width: 1em;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #ccc;
}

.rate:not(:checked) > span label:before {
  content: "★ ";
}

.rate > span input:checked ~ label {
  color: #ffc700;
}

.rate:not(:checked) > span label:hover,
.rate:not(:checked) > span label:hover ~ label {
  color: #deb217;
}
```

```html
<div dir ="rtl" class="rate" onclick="validate()">
  <span>
    <input type="radio" id="star5" data-product-id="@Model.ProductId" class="star" name="rate" value="5" />
    <label for="star5"  title="5 Stars">5 stars</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star4" data-product-id="@Model.ProductId" class="star" name="rate" value="" />
    <label for="star4"  title="4 Star">4 stars</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star3" data-product-id="@Model.ProductId" class="star" name="rate" value="3" />
    <label for="star3" title="3 Star">3 stars</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star2" data-product-id="@Model.ProductId" class="star" name="rate" value="2" />
    <label for="star2" title="2 Stars">2 stars</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star1" data-product-id="@Model.ProductId" class="star" name="rate" value="1" />
    <label for="star1" title="1 Star">1 star</label>  
  </span>
  <p>אני מניח שיש כאן הודעה?</p>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="rate" onclick="validate()">
  <span>
    <input type="radio" id="star5a" data-product-id="@Model.ProductId" class="star" name="rate" value="5" />
    <label for="star5a"  title="5 Stars">5 stars</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star4a" data-product-id="@Model.ProductId" class="star" name="rate" value="" />
    <label for="star4a"  title="4 Star">4 stars</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star3a" data-product-id="@Model.ProductId" class="star" name="rate" value="3" />
    <label for="star3a" title="3 Star">3 stars</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star2a" data-product-id="@Model.ProductId" class="star" name="rate" value="2" />
    <label for="star2a" title="2 Stars">2 stars</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star1a" data-product-id="@Model.ProductId" class="star" name="rate" value="1" />
    <label for="star1a" title="1 Star">1 star</label>  
  </span>
  <p>I guess there is content aside here ?</p>
</div>
```

---

A few links than could be usefull aside this answer.

---

- [codepen to play with](https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/eYZrrGY)
- [flex reminder/tutorial](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) & [`flex-direction` reference/guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction)
- [html DIR attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/dir)
- [direction CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/direction)

Answer (score 1):

The direction from right to left or left to right is related to `direction` syntax in CSS.
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_direction.asp

So, you can have from right to left with:

```
direction: rtl;
```

and from left to right with:

```
direction: ltr;
```

Comment: Thank you,it's worked fine but the solution of :display: inline-flex;
  flex-flow: row-reverse; it's perfect for my design, thanks again

Answer (score 1):

I used flex flow property with row-reverse value.
I think this solution may help you to solve your problem. And I used float property with left value to get rate div to left position.

```css
.rate {
  display: flex;
  height: 46px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  flex-flow: row-reverse wrap;
  float: left;
}

.rate:not(:checked)>input {
  position: absolute;
  top: -9999px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.rate:not(:checked)>label {
  float: right;
  width: 1em;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #ccc;
}

.rate:not(:checked)>label:before {
  content: '★ ';
}

.rate>input:checked~label {
  color: #ffc700;
}

.rate:not(:checked)>label:hover,
.rate:not(:checked)>label:hover~label {
  color: #deb217;
}
```

```html
<div class="rate" onclick="validate()">
  <input type="radio" id="star5" class="star" name="rate" value="5" />
  <label for="star5">5 stars</label>
  <input type="radio" id="star4" class="star" name="rate" value="4" />
  <label for="star4">4 stars</label>
  <input type="radio" id="star3" class="star" name="rate" value="3" />
  <label for="star3">3 stars</label>
  <input type="radio" id="star2" class="star" name="rate" value="2" />
  <label for="star2">2 stars</label>
  <input type="radio" id="star1" class="star" name="rate" value="1" />
  <label for="star1">1 star</label>
```